# How to set Content-Type as application/json in httpkit

Tags: json, clojure, http-headers, content-type, http-kit

I use [httpkit](http://www.http-kit.org/client.html) as http client. I try many solutions to make the header `Content-Type` be `application/json`, but all failed.

Here is my code:

```
(require '[org.httpkit.client :as http])

(http/post 
  url
  { :query-params {"q" "foo, bar"}
    :form-params {"q" "foo, bar"}
    :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json; charset=utf-8"}})
```

Post with the code above would get `response status 200` but `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

And if delete the line `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, would get `response status 400`.

PS: I take [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) as web server.

Comment: Is it possible that you are expecting your **request** `Content-Type` to modify the *response* `Content-Type` header? If so, then you should be looking into the implementation of the endpoint in your web server, not the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `httpkit` (can recommend `clj-http`) but I think you should use the  `:body` option instead of `:form-params` to specify payload as the latter would [force](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/blob/master/src/org/httpkit/client.clj#L28) the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It makes sense considering how [form params](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms) work in HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

What request do you want to send?

- `:query-params` will attach `?q=foo,bar` to the request url
- `:form-params` will make the body `q=foo,bar` with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

That's probably more than needed, but then the body has to be `application/json` too, besides already being `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you want a json body, you could do:

```
:body (clojure.data.json/write-str {:q "foo,bar"})
```

Comment: @schaueho, thanks for the edit, my formatting was really ugly.